# use of numbers within name of UDF in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I added the following functions:

```
Function map() As Integer
   map = 1
End Function
Function map_2() As Integer
   map_2 = 1
End Function
Function map2() As Integer
   map2 = 1
End Function
```

The first two functions work. But the last one - doesn't - I am getting `#REF` error. Why is it?

It looks like excel treats them as cell address.

I tried `map22()`, `mpa22()`, `map333()` - they don't work. But `map_22()`, `map_333()` work.
I am using Excel 2013

Comment: I tried them , and all worked as expected.

Comment: You probably have something else named `map2`.

Comment: I get a #REF error because it thinks it is column MAP, Row 2.

Comment: Yes, it's because that is a valid cell address.

Comment: @Warcupine yes, `mmmmmmmmm1()` works

Comment: As an aside, your `map()` function will overwrite a [built-in function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-function-48006093-f97c-47c1-bfcc-749263bb1f01) for anyone using excel 365.

Comment: It is a good idea to use the `Option Explicit` statement in VBA it might clear up misunderstandings in the code, would it help in this case and affect your `#REF` error? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement

Answer (score 0):

The Reason is because Excel treats 1, 2 or 3 letters followed by any number of letters as a cell reference:

- `=A1`
  Reference to Cell A1
- `=BB22`
  Reference to Cell BB22
- `=MAP2`
  Reference to nonexistent Cell MAP2
  As in: Column "MAP", Row "2"

If we make the same general arrangement with "Real" cells, we get the same ref.

[image]
[image]

I would encourage to you use your `=MAP_1` as I don't really know any way around it.

Comment: `MAP` is column 8830 (`Debug.Print Range("MAP2").Column`).

Comment: ha HA! I though we only went into the double character columns. When I read that I hit End(xlright) and found out i was sorely mistaken.